# replace text string in C#

Tags: c#, string, escaping

Hi I have a basic mistake because I do not look at is how to fix the code:

```
string code = 'dsad {"scans": dssadasd';
code = code.Replace('{"scans":','test');
```

the problem is that it fails due to strange characters in the first replacement

anyone can help me?

pd :

sorry here have the original line and I forget show, as I have to do the same with this line :

```
code = code.Replace('"(.*?)": {"detected": (.*?), "version": (.*?), "result": (.*?), "update": (.*?)}','test');
```

Comment: There is no way that code would even compile. Please provide code that compiles and provide specific error message(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. in your first string, you should:

   - use `\` to escape the double quotes inside the string;
   - *or* prepend the string with `@` and escape with `""`

     ```
      string code = "dsad {\"scans\": dssadasd";
      string code = @"dsad {""scans"": dssadasd";
     ```
2. the `'` character is used to delimit `char`s, not strings. You should use `"` instead.

   ```
   code = code.Replace("{\"scans\":","test");
   ```

Comment: +1 The only answer that goes on to explain why it fails (use of `'` vs `"`).

Comment: In verbatim (`@`) strings, you use `""` to escape double quotes; as-is, your code won't compile.

Comment: thanks for the help but update the post with the original line, I apologize for not show

Comment: @user3015248 The same rules apply - so.. apply them. `code = code.Replace("\"(.*?)\": {\"detected\": (.*?), \"version\": (.*?), \"result\": (.*?), \"update\": (.*?)}","test");`

Answer (score 2):

You have to scape the strings

```
string code = "dsad {\"scans\": dssadasd";
code = code.Replace("{\"scans\":","test");
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not compilable C#. Strings are always double-quoted in C#:

```
string code = "dsad {\"scans\": dssadasd";
code = code.Replace("{\"scans\":", "test");
```

C# isn't JavaScript :)

Answer (score 0):

That code is not a valid C#. You need to use double-quotes to represent a string and escape the double-quotes inside of the string:

```
string code = "dsad {\"scans\": dssadasd";
code = code.Replace("{\"scans\":","test");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
    string code = "dsad {\"scans\": dssadasd";
    code = code.Replace("{\"scans\":", "test");
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the double quotes.

```
string code = "dsad {\"scans\": dssadasd";
code = code.Replace("{\"scans":',"test");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the double quotes.

```
string code = "dsad {\"scans\": dssadasd";
code = code.Replace("{\"scans\":", "test");
```

You also need to use double quotes rather than single quotes for `string`s- single quotes are only for `char` values in C#.